# CMake Error: Could NOT find Boost (missing: system filesystem thread log locale regex chrono atomic date_time) (found version "1.75.0")

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, build

I am attempting to build and run a c++ program from GitHub, although i keep running into problems presumably with Cmake and the boost libraries. It is the first time i have tried building a program, so there is probably something obvious missing.

The program in question is from the following GitHub repository: https://github.com/antimix/PrusaSlicer. I am opening the folder i Visual Studio Code as an administrator (to remove some other error) with the Cmake and Cmake tools extensions installed. I have installed 1.75.0 Boost from this site: https://boost.teeks99.com/. From the Visual Code terminal I get the following error(s):

```
[cmake] CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
[cmake]   Could NOT find Boost (missing: system filesystem thread log locale regex
[cmake]   chrono atomic date_time) (found version "1.75.0")
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
[cmake]   C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2344 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
[cmake]   CMakeLists.txt:266 (find_package)
```

And here is the full log:

```
[variant] Loaded new set of variants
[kit] Successfully loaded 8 kits from C:\Users\*user*\AppData\Local\CMakeTools\cmake-tools-kits.json
[main] Configuring folder: PrusaSlicer-dribbling_2.2.0 
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" "-Hc:/Program Files/Prusa3D/PrusaSlicer-dribbling_2.2.0" "-Bc:/Program Files/Prusa3D/PrusaSlicer-dribbling_2.2.0/build" -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -T host=x64 -A win32
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE "-Hc:/Program Files/Prusa3D/PrusaSlicer-dribbling_2.2.0" "-Bc:/Program Files/Prusa3D/PrusaSlicer-dribbling_2.2.0/build" -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -T host=x64 -A win32
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.18363.
[cmake] -- SLIC3R_ASAN: OFF
[cmake] -- SLIC3R_BUILD_SANDBOXES: OFF
[cmake] -- SLIC3R_BUILD_TESTS: ON
[cmake] -- SLIC3R_FHS: OFF
[cmake] -- SLIC3R_GTK: 2
[cmake] -- SLIC3R_GUI: ON
[cmake] -- SLIC3R_MSVC_COMPILE_PARALLEL: ON
[cmake] -- SLIC3R_MSVC_PDB: ON
[cmake] -- SLIC3R_PCH: ON
[cmake] -- SLIC3R_PERL_XS: OFF
[cmake] Building without Win10 Netfabb STL fixing service support
[cmake] -- SLIC3R_PROFILE: OFF
[cmake] -- SLIC3R_STATIC: ON
[cmake] -- SLIC3R_WX_STABLE: ON
[cmake] -- SLIC3R_STATIC: ON
[cmake] -- CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: (default)
[cmake] CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
[cmake]   Could NOT find Boost (missing: system filesystem thread log locale regex
[cmake]   chrono atomic date_time) (found version "1.75.0")
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
[cmake]   C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2344 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
[cmake]   CMakeLists.txt:266 (find_package)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
[cmake] See also "C:/Program Files/Prusa3D/PrusaSlicer-dribbling_2.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
[cmake] See also "C:/Program Files/Prusa3D/PrusaSlicer-dribbling_2.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Also, here is the two logs that the terminal talk about if that is of interest:

*CMakeOutput.log*

```
    The system is: Windows - 10.0.18363 - AMD64
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
0
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.3+39993bd9d for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 21-02-2021 22:55:20.
Project "C:\Program Files\Prusa3D\PrusaSlicer-dribbling_2.2.0\build\CMakeFiles\3.20.0-rc1\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "Debug\".
  Creating directory "Debug\CompilerIdC.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "Debug\CompilerIdC.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX64\x86\CL.exe /c /nologo /W0 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Oy- /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /FC /errorReport:queue CMakeCCompilerId.c
  CMakeCCompilerId.c
Link:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX64\x86\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:".\CompilerIdC.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /PDB:".\CompilerIdC.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:".\CompilerIdC.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH Debug\CMakeCCompilerId.obj
  CompilerIdC.vcxproj -> C:\Program Files\Prusa3D\PrusaSlicer-dribbling_2.2.0\build\CMakeFiles\3.20.0-rc1\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.exe
PostBuildEvent:
  for %%i in (cl.exe) do @echo CMAKE_C_COMPILER=%%~$PATH:i
  :VCEnd
  CMAKE_C_COMPILER=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\Hostx64\x86\cl.exe
FinalizeBuildStatus:
  Deleting file "Debug\CompilerIdC.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
  Touching "Debug\CompilerIdC.tlog\CompilerIdC.lastbuildstate".
Done Building Project "C:\Program Files\Prusa3D\PrusaSlicer-dribbling_2.2.0\build\CMakeFiles\3.20.0-rc1\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" (default targets).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.39


Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "CompilerIdC.exe"

Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "CompilerIdC.vcxproj"

The C compiler identification is MSVC, found in "C:/Program Files/Prusa3D/PrusaSlicer-dribbling_2.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/3.20.0-rc1/CompilerIdC/CompilerIdC.exe"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
0
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.3+39993bd9d for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 21-02-2021 22:55:21.
Project "C:\Program Files\Prusa3D\PrusaSlicer-dribbling_2.2.0\build\CMakeFiles\3.20.0-rc1\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "Debug\".
  Creating directory "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX64\x86\CL.exe /c /nologo /W0 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Oy- /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /FC /errorReport:queue CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
  CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
Link:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX64\x86\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:".\CompilerIdCXX.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /PDB:".\CompilerIdCXX.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:".\CompilerIdCXX.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH Debug\CMakeCXXCompilerId.obj
  CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj -> C:\Program Files\Prusa3D\PrusaSlicer-dribbling_2.2.0\build\CMakeFiles\3.20.0-rc1\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.exe
PostBuildEvent:
  for %%i in (cl.exe) do @echo CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=%%~$PATH:i
  :VCEnd
  CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\Hostx64\x86\cl.exe
FinalizeBuildStatus:
  Deleting file "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
  Touching "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\CompilerIdCXX.lastbuildstate".
Done Building Project "C:\Program Files\Prusa3D\PrusaSlicer-dribbling_2.2.0\build\CMakeFiles\3.20.0-rc1\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (default targets).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.11


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "CompilerIdCXX.exe"

Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj"

The CXX compiler identification is MSVC, found in "C:/Program Files/Prusa3D/PrusaSlicer-dribbling_2.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/3.20.0-rc1/CompilerIdCXX/CompilerIdCXX.exe"

Detecting C compiler ABI info compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Program Files/Prusa3D/PrusaSlicer-dribbling_2.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe cmTC_e9c90.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=win32 /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /v:m && Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.3+39993bd9d for .NET Framework

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29336 for x86

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

  CMakeCCompilerABI.c

  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_e9c90.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_e9c90.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:queue "C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.20\Modules\CMakeCCompilerABI.c"

  cmTC_e9c90.vcxproj -> C:\Program Files\Prusa3D\PrusaSlicer-dribbling_2.2.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_e9c90.exe




Detecting CXX compiler ABI info compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Program Files/Prusa3D/PrusaSlicer-dribbling_2.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe cmTC_65605.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=win32 /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /v:m && Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.3+39993bd9d for .NET Framework

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29336 for x86

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

  CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp

  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR /Fo"cmTC_65605.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_65605.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:queue "C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.20\Modules\CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp"

  cmTC_65605.vcxproj -> C:\Program Files\Prusa3D\PrusaSlicer-dribbling_2.2.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_65605.exe
```

*CMakeError.log*

```
Determining if the include file pthread.h exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Program Files/Prusa3D/PrusaSlicer-dribbling_2.2.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe cmTC_3680a.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=win32 /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /v:m && Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.3+39993bd9d for .NET Framework

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29336 for x86

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

  CheckIncludeFile.c

  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_3680a.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_3680a.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:queue "C:\Program Files\Prusa3D\PrusaSlicer-dribbling_2.2.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckIncludeFile.c"

C:\Program Files\Prusa3D\PrusaSlicer-dribbling_2.2.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckIncludeFile.c(1,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pthread.h': No such file or directory [C:\Program Files\Prusa3D\PrusaSlicer-dribbling_2.2.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_3680a.vcxproj]
```

I have looked around at some different threads to find a solution but without luck. Most of them revolve around setting the system environment variables for Boost, but it seems that Cmake gives a message that it ignores this variable. I have also found a thread that suggests adding a line in the CMakeLists.txt to set the boost path before loading the libraries (as far as I understand), but none of these things unfortunately helped.

Hope some of you have a solution for this headscratcher...

Comment: From that `teeks` page: "These are just the binaries, to use them, you will need to have the same version of Boost already installed." Have you also installed the Boost header files themselves from the official repository?

Comment: When configure the project, add for CMake option `Boost_DEBUG` set to `ON`. With this option you could see which actual files are searched for Boost. Compare these files with ones you actually have. So you could have a hint about the problem.

Comment: Thanks @KenY-N , that fixed one error. Now I am stuck with installing the TBB library, but I do see how Tsyvarev's solution could help with that. I'll try that later. Thanks a lot.